# How to auto-increment in posgresql?

Tags: postgresql, auto-increment, star-schema

i have a star schema datawarehouse i did the load with python and i set the `id` of the employee = `id` in the database , ron has `id` number = 99 , Tom =201 ,Alice =87 but in the database i found the id where set by default . should i add another column `id_employee` or should i change the `id` into the real `id` also i want the fact_table to have the real `id`
[image: Employee table]

the code i used to load the database :

```
for row in pandasSource:
    row["id"]=row["id_employee"]
    dimemployee.ensure(row)
connection.commit()
connection.close
pgconn.close()
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand. How is the table defined, and with what SQL statements did you add the rows?

Comment: this is dimension employee , i did the load using python and psycopg2 including the mapping  , `id` is the primary key , in the python code that i have the id is different of what i get in database

Comment: I asked for the table definition and the SQL statement that inserted the rows.

Comment: its edited now.

Answer (score 0):

Dimensions should have auto-incremented surrogate keys as their primary keys. PKs from source tables should be held as columns in your dimensions

Comment: so its like an artificial key ?

Comment: yes, that’s correct

Comment: i see but i want the real id linked with the fact table and it fills automatically like auto-increment

Comment: You put SKs in a fact table, not the keys from a source system